# How to place over centered element?

Tags: html, css

I have a little website programmed containing an area with three divs centered in the middle. I am trying to put a `<h2>` over it like this:[image]

But best I could do was to place the Locations `<h2>` along with the divs in the center using `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;` in the `#locationsbg` but for now I just replaced it and let the Locations away.

```css
* {
    background-color: black;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    color: seashell;
    opacity: 0.9;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
}

#locations {
    display: inline-flex;
    background-color: transparent;
}

#locationsbg {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 500px;
    width: 1200px;
    background-image: url(https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-locations-background.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#locationsbg h2 {
    background-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
}

#locations div {
    max-height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 40px;
    opacity: 1; 
}
```

```html
<section id="locationsbg">
  <!--<h2>Locations</h2> This should be over the centered divs (not in the real center-->
  <div id="locations">
    <div>
      <h3>Downtown</h3>
      <p>384 West 4th St</p>
      <p>Suite 108</p>
      <p>Portland, Maine</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>East Bayside</h3>
      <p>3433 Phisherman's Avenue</p>
      <p>(Northwest Corner)</p>
      <p>Portland, Maine</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Oakdale</h3>
      <p>515 Crescent Avenue</p>
      <p>Second Floor</p>
      <p>Portland, Maine</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now there is a slightly awkward structure that is difficult to work with. Wrap H2 tag with div and use any properties to move the elements inside it. Highly recommend using a grid for the elements inside #locations. As far as I understand, you will need the following code fpr example:

```css
.heading-wrapper{
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  padding:15px 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="locationsbg">
  <div class="heading-wrapper">
    <h2>Locations</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="locations">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</section>
```

or use the same grid for splitting and centering. But I still don't understand why you use such structure, it can be made easier with less code.

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex-direction: column` to the `#locationsbg` element and then remove the ***positioning*** in the h2 element. Remove *this* `position: relative; top: 40px;` *from* =>  ***#locationsbg h2***.

```css
* {
    background-color: black;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    color: seashell;
    opacity: 0.9;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
}

#locations {
    display: inline-flex;
    background-color: transparent;
}

#locationsbg {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 500px;
    width: 1200px;
    background-image: url(https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-locations-background.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#locationsbg h2 {
    background-color: transparent;
}

#locations div {
    max-height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 40px;
    opacity: 1; 
}
```

```html
<section id="locationsbg">
  <h2>Locations</h2>
  <div id="locations">
    <div>
      <h3>Downtown</h3>
      <p>384 West 4th St</p>
      <p>Suite 108</p>
      <p>Portland, Maine</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>East Bayside</h3>
      <p>3433 Phisherman's Avenue</p>
      <p>(Northwest Corner)</p>
      <p>Portland, Maine</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Oakdale</h3>
      <p>515 Crescent Avenue</p>
      <p>Second Floor</p>
      <p>Portland, Maine</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```